# When did Turing's results become impactful in computer science?

Tags: history

Turing was working on a mathematical problem, not a computational one, and computers of a sort existed before his work. At what point did the researchers working on computers realize that Turing's results were important for their work, and when was it that Turing's results became incorporated into their research?

I suppose this might boil down to: "what was the first computer science paper published that referenced Turing's work", but that may be spectacularly hard to find...

Comment: This question doesn't really make much sense without naming _what_ specific impact, which results and which work of Turing you're referring to. Any valid answer would need that - as you already mention.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be migrated to https://cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The question appears to be about 'computer science', whereas this forum seems to be mostly concerned with computers and computer programs.

Comment: Before you can answer "what was the first computer science paper published that referenced Turing's work", you'd have to answer "what was the first computer science paper" first, i.e., at which point, exactly, did computer science separate from mathematics at one end and electrical engineering at the other, and become its own academic discipline. There's bound to be a rather large grey area.

Comment: What do you mean, "researchers working on computers?" Are you talking about engineers _designing_ computing machinery? There is not much connection between Turing's work and actual computer architecture. In fact, that was the whole point of the Turing machine. He considered the architecture of the actual computing machinery of his day to be intractable to mathematical analysis because of its complexity. Instead, he studied the power of the simplest architecture he could imagine—the Turing Machine—that still would be capable of "computing."

Comment: We can maybe talk about Turing's ["Scheme A"](http://curation.cs.manchester.ac.uk/computer50/www.computer50.org/mark1/program.html#progorg) for the Manchester Mark 1, and how it absolutely failed to advance the design of the man-machine interface :-)

Comment: I would think that [Wayne Conrad's suggestion](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25529/when-did-turings-results-become-impactful-in-computer-science/25530?noredirect=1#comment86076_25530) of SE's [History of Science and Mathematics](hsm.stackexchange.com) is a spot on target for a move.

Comment: The problem is that the definition of "computer science", as distinct from other fields, remains elusive. In fact virtually the only thing people agree on, is that computer science has nothing to do with computers (or as Dijkstra put it, computer science has as much to do with computers, as astronomy has to do with telescopes). It's also worth noting that in Turing's heyday, "computers" were a kind of employee who performed computation with paper and pencil, not a kind of machine.

Answer (score 5):

The Turing machine was only one particular way of trying to capture a notion of computability, other researchers (Gödel, Kleene, Church, Post, Rosser) worked on related problems at the same time. As the Wikipedia article on the so-called [Church-Turing Thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis) describes,

> Church, Kleene, and Turing proved that these three formally defined classes of computable functions coincide: a function is λ-computable if and only if it is Turing computable, and if and only if it is general recursive. This has led mathematicians and computer scientists to believe that the concept of computability is accurately characterized by these three equivalent processes. Other formal attempts to characterize computability have subsequently strengthened this belief

The equivalences were proven 1936/1937. So I guess that would be "the first computer science papers published that referenced Turing's work".

(Not sure if this is really a retrocomputing question, it's more about computer science).

Comment: Also it's not about computers or computing (in sense of using computers), but computability whoch is a mathematical issue, so rather something for Math.SE, isn't it?

Comment: @Raffzahn Or maybe https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your conclusion. These papers were all written by people who considered themselves mathematicians, and appeared in mathematical journals. I'm pretty sure everyone involved at the time would have considered them math (rather than cs) papers.

Comment: @WayneConrad Maybe even better as that would be right on their area.

Comment: @MichaelGraf  You're right.  Not to start a flame war, but CS is basically a branch of math.  To paraphrase one of my CS profs: computer science has very little to do with actual computers.  Things like algorithmic complexity and information compression are still mathematically intriguing topics, even without computers.  If computers had never been invented, CS would still have developed as a field, slowly, and become an esoteric branch of formal logic.

Comment: @RETRAC: The famous CS book *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs* (universally known as SICP) has a quip along the lines that if we named other sciences the way we named Computer Science, we would call Astronomy "Telescope Science" or Biology "Microscope Science". I.e. the computer is a tool (of many) to study the object of CS, but it is not, itself, the object of CS. In many languages, including my own native German, the field is actually named based on a neologism constructed from the word "Information" and the suffix -ics, i.e. *informatics*.

Comment: In some Romance languages, it is called the equivalent of Comput**ing** Science (note the subtle difference). In Danish, it is called the equivalent of Datalogy.